# Laravel: How to Email Users once Form submitted with page id

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel-4

I have a form in laravel.
If submits a bunch of information about the user and then submits it to a store() function.

```
public function store()
    {

            $input = Input::except('_token');

        if ( ! $this->validator->with($input)->passes())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->validator->errors())->withInput($input);
        }

        $this->title->save($input);

        return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('main.created successfully') );
    }

public function save()
    {
        if ($this->query && $this->values)
        {
            return DB::statement($this->query, array_values($this->values));
        }       
    }
```

The query is executed in the `save()` function

The User can then access the info at `www.mysite/{$id}`

The `{$id}` variable is generated when the query is executed and saved into my db.  It is the value of the `id` column in my db.

I want to email the user when they submit the form to say that the info has been entered successfully and that they can view it at `www.mysite/{$id}` but I don't know what variable I should put into my `mailer()` function to denote the `{$id}` because that variable is generated when it is saved.  How do I implement a way to pass the `{$id}` variable to my `mailer()` function?

Comment: You can insert into DB using query builders `insertGetId` function. Look in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#inserts) Knowing the ID, you could pass it further to your functions

Comment: oh ok. I didn't know about insertGETid